# Calculating pdf of minimum of i.i.d. random variables with threshold condition

Tags: probability

Let say I have $m$ i.i.d uniform random variables $U_1, U_2,...U_m$ that range between 0 and 1. I generate $m$ number by using each of random variable and select the one which is minimum among the numbers that exceed threshold. My goal is to obtain pdf of minimum of random variables that exceed a threshold $\gamma$.

Let me rephrase,

1. I generate $m$ number by using uniform distribution $\sim U\left(0,1\right)$.
2. I select the numbers which are bigger than $\gamma$.
3. I select the minimum number.

How can I find the pdf of this number? In my opinion, the problem is not easy as it seems.

Comment: If $\ 0<\gamma\le1\ $, then there's a positive probability $\ \gamma^m\ $ that $\ U_i<\gamma\ $ for all $\ i=1,2,\dots, m\ $.  In that case, the set of numbers you can select in step $2$ will be empty.  What do you then do in step $3$?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to assume that $\gamma^m$ is very small that we can simply ignore.

Comment: Which is $m$ ? The total count of random variables, or the index of the minimum among those?

Comment: Hello Graham, $m$ is total count of random variables.

Comment: Your phrasing is confusing. "I generate $m$ number" Do you mean "I generate $m$ random numbers" ($U_1$,... $U_m$ ..., with $m$ given) or, "I generate a random number $m$"?

Comment: I am sorry for confusion. I mean "I generate $m$ random numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ G=\big|\{\,i\ |\,U_i<\gamma\,\}\big|\ $ and $\ V\ $ be the value of the number you choose in step $3$. Then $\ \mathbb{P}\big(G=g\big)=$$\,{m\choose g}\gamma^g(1-\gamma)^{m-g}\ $, and given that $\ G=g\ $ there are $\ m-g\ $ of the variates $\ U_1,U_2,\dots,U_m\ $ that will be uniformly distributed over the interval $\ [\gamma,1]\ $, and the minimum of them will be greater than $\ x\in[\gamma,1]\ $ if and only if all $\ m-g\ $ of them are.  Therefore $\ \mathbb{P}\big(V> x\,|\,G=g\big)=$$\,\left(\frac{1-x}{1-\gamma}\right)^{m-g}\ $ for $\ x\in[\gamma,1]\ $ and $\ g=0,1,\dots, m-1\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(V> x\big)&=\sum_{g=0}^{m-1}\mathbb{P}\big(V> x\,|\,G=g\big)\mathbb{P}\big(G=g\big)\\
&=\sum_{g=0}^{m-1}{m\choose g}\gamma^g(1-x)^{m-g}\\
&=(1+\gamma-x)^m-\gamma^m\ .
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(\{V\le x\}\cup\{V\ \text{is undefined}\}\big)=1+\gamma^m-(1+\gamma-x)^m\ .
$$
If we take the probability, $\ \gamma^m\ $, of $\ V$'s being undefined as negligible, as the OP indicates as being the case in a comment, we get
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(V\le x\big)=1-(1+\gamma-x)^m
$$
for the cumulative distribution function of $\ V\ $, and
$$
p_V(x)=m(1+\gamma-x)^{m-1}
$$
for its density function.

Answer (score 0):

This minimum number is a discrete random variable taking values in a finite set. As such I think it is enough to calculate the $m+1$ probabilities below:
The minimum number is
$$
M=\min_{i=1,...,m}\{i:U_i>\gamma\}\,.
$$
When there is no $U_i>\gamma$ this set is empty and $M$ is undefined as remarked by ***lonza leggiera***. It is common to define $M=\infty$ in this case but any value other than $1,....,m$ will do.

Now $M$ is a decent random variable with values in
$\{1,...,m,\infty\}$. Its probability distribution is given by
\begin{alignat}{1}
P\{M=1\}&=P\{U_1>\gamma\}&=1-\gamma\,,\\[2mm]
P\{M=2\}&=P\{U_1\le\gamma,U_2>\gamma\}&=\gamma(1-\gamma)\,,\\[2mm]
&\vdots\\[2mm]
P\{M=m\}&=P\{U_1\le\gamma,...,U_{m-1}\le\gamma,U_m>\gamma\}&=\gamma^{m-1}(1-\gamma)\,,\\[2mm]
P\{M=\infty\}&=P\{U_1\le\gamma,...,U_m\le\gamma\}&=\gamma^m\,.
\end{alignat}